# Textarea outline just black on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

so I'm trying to finish up my portfolio website and I'm stuck on this dreaded contact form.

So here's my webpage.. www.heatherkirk.net/contact.php

On Chrome and (I'm guessing Safari since those two are the similar it seems), the textarea box looks different than compared to other browsers. I'm just wondering how to get the darker color on top and the lighter color throughout on the Comments part for Chrome instead of just the black outline. If anyone could help me out, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Styling input elements is notoriously difficult. Not only does every browser style it differently, operating systems also play a role. (Edit: Not implying you shouldn't try. Just giving you a head's up.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Chrome's property inspector (right click, Inspect Element) says your inputs have `border: 2px inset`, and your textarea has `border: 1px solid`. Try changing that?

Firefox's property inspector doesn't show any value for `border` at all for the `textarea`, though, so that (and looking through your stylesheet) leads me to think that you've applied `border-radius`, but haven't set a `border` for your textarea at all; it just happens that Firefox's default `textarea` has a `2px inset` border, and Webkit's (Chrome/Safari) has a `1px black` one.

Add a `border: 2px inset` to your `textarea` style, and that should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the `border-radius` the black outline disappears.

But if you need to keep the rounded corners, then just add `border-width:0px` to the textarea style.

Like the user above mentioned, when you just have `border:solid 1px;` the default color is black, adjust that a bit.

Answer (score 0):

set `border:0 none;` to your textarea in css